# How can I shuffle a part of list for all permutations in python?

Tags: python, list, shuffle

I have a following list of lists:

```
columns1 = ["title", "abstract","groups"]
columns2 = ["title", "abstract","groups","keywords"]
columns3 = ["title", "abstract","groups","topics"]
columns4 = ["title", "abstract","groups","keywords","topics"]
columns5 = ["title", "abstract","groups","topics","keywords"]
columns6 = ["title", "abstract","keywords"]
columns7 = ["title", "abstract","keywords","groups"]
columns8 = ["title", "abstract","keywords","topics"]
columns9 = ["title", "abstract","keywords","groups","topics"]
columns10 = ["title", "abstract","keywords","topics","groups"]
columns11 = ["title", "abstract","topics"]
columns12 = ["title", "abstract","topics","groups"]
columns13 = ["title", "abstract","topics","keywords"]
columns14 = ["title", "abstract","topics","groups","keywords"]
columns15 = ["title", "abstract","topics","keywords","groups"]
```

As you see, I want to keep the first two as they are and shuffle the next three words for all different permutations(or combinations - I forgot which one).

How can I create this list with a loop?

Comment: Keeping shuffling a list seems like a very inefficient way to get all permutations. Why not using `itertools.permutations`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a permutation and not a combination, since you want to consider that `[a,b,c]` is different from `[a,c,b]`

To do so, you can create a loop like this :

```
elements_base = ["title", "abstract"]
elements_plus = ["groups","topics","keywords"]

import itertools
for i in range(3):
    for element in itertools.permutations(elements_plus,i+1):
        print(elements_base + list(element))
```

The result is :

```
['title', 'abstract', 'groups']
['title', 'abstract', 'topics']
['title', 'abstract', 'keywords']
['title', 'abstract', 'groups', 'topics']
['title', 'abstract', 'groups', 'keywords']
['title', 'abstract', 'topics', 'groups']
['title', 'abstract', 'topics', 'keywords']
['title', 'abstract', 'keywords', 'groups']
['title', 'abstract', 'keywords', 'topics']
['title', 'abstract', 'groups', 'topics', 'keywords']
['title', 'abstract', 'groups', 'keywords', 'topics']
['title', 'abstract', 'topics', 'groups', 'keywords']
['title', 'abstract', 'topics', 'keywords', 'groups']
['title', 'abstract', 'keywords', 'groups', 'topics']
['title', 'abstract', 'keywords', 'topics', 'groups']
```